# how to make the if else code better, React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make the if else code I become reusable or use a switch, how do I use the switch?

this my code :

```
handleChange = (selectedkey) => {
    this.setState({ activeKey: selectedkey })
    if (selectedkey === '1') {
      this.updateTabNotPay();
    } else if (selectedkey === '2') {
      this.updateTabNotSent();
    } else if (selectedkey === '3') {
      this.updateTabInDelivery();
    } else if (selectedkey === '4') {
      this.updateTabFinish();
    } else if (selectedkey === '5') {
      this.updateTabCancel();
    }
  };
```

Comment: Did you check any documentation about how to write switch statements in JavaScript ?

Comment: how to use it, can you give an example with my code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid `switch`, and instead use an object indexed by `selectedkey`, whose values are the associated function names:

```
const keyFnNames = {
  '1': 'updateTabNotPay',
  '2': 'updateTabNotSent',
  '3': 'updateTabInDelivery',
  '4': 'updateTabFinish',
  '5': 'updateTabCancel'
};

// ...

handleChange = (selectedkey) => {
  this.setState({ activeKey: selectedkey })
  const fnName = keyFnNames[selectedKey];
  if (fnName) {
    this[fnName]();
  }
};
```

If you know that `selectedKey` will always have a corresponding function, then you can levae out the `if (fnName)` check.

Using `switch` instead would be unnecessarily verbose and more error-prone, IMO.

Comment: I want to ask, what is the function of this [], for example this [....]

Comment: That's bracket notation, it allows you to access a property name by a variable, eg `foo = 'prop'; obj[foo]` accesses `obj.prop`

Answer (score 0):

i suppose something like this could work ?

```js
    handleChange = (selectkey) => {
this.state({ activeKey: selectedkey })
switch(selectedkey){
case 1:
this.updateTabNotPay();
break;
case 2:
this.updateTabNotSent();
break;
case 3:
this.updateTabInDelivery();
break;
case 4:
this.updateTabFinish();
break;
case 5:
this.updateTabCancel();
break;
default:
console.log("error");
}
}
```

**strong text**